Change data source for tests
I have an adhoc integration-test database which works great. It gets created from scratch for each test-run, the entity mapper is Hibernate 6.5, Java is JDK 21 and Spring Boot is version 3.3.4.
Now, I want to be able to operate on the database as different users, which have different rights on the DB tables.
Is there any way to change the data source / user in Spring Boot after it started, for integration-tests? On-the-fly, mid-test-method and with an arbitrary user-name?
Like this:
interface MyObjectRepository extends CrudRepository ...

... class Testing { ...
  void testing() {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();

    setDataSourceUser("SuperUser")
    assertNotNull(myObjectRepository.save(myObject));

    setDataSourceUser("SimpleUser")
    assertThrows(NoRightsExceptions.class, () -> myObjectRepository.save(myObject));
  }

